# css class not working properly

Tags: html, css

i'm redesigning my website. and doing that i'm finding myself in some problems using the css code i wrote.

i use div's to get an image and some text next to each other.
i'm unable to get the text moved to the correct place (see pictures) the margin-left doesn't seem to work when it is in the css file but it works when directly embedded in the div tags, am i doing something wrong?

also i'dd like to add that i don't need to set the image size in the html code but its in the css code is this possible?

What i get

[image: What i get]

What i want

[image: What i want]

```css
body
{
 background:#333 url(bg.jpg) repeat top left;
 font-family:Arial;
 color:white;
 text-align:center;
}

body header.heading
{
 width:1150px;
 /*background:transparent url(../images/menu/MEbanner.jpg) no-repeat top;
 background-size: 1150 100px;
 padding-top:101px;*/
 margin:0 auto;
 z-index:0;
 
}


body.Content
{
 width:1150px;
}

main
{
width:1150px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

section 
{
 text-align:left;
 margin:0 auto;
}

header nav
{
 width:1150px;
 background:transparent url(../images/menu/MEbanner.jpg) no-repeat top;
 background-size: 1150 100px;
 padding-top:101px;
 margin:0 auto;
 z-index:0;
}

header nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

header nav li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

header nav li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

/*header nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}*/

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
header nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

header nav li.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

header nav li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header nav li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color:  #111;
}

header nav li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

nav 
{
 text-align:left;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.hidden {display:none}

hr
{ 
 border-left: none;
 border-right: none;
 height:4px;
 margin: 2em 0 2em 0;
}

main a:link {color:#fff;}      /* unvisited link */

main a:visited {color:#fff;}  /* visited link */

main a:hover {color:#159;}  /* mouse over link */

blockquote{
 color:white; 
 border-left: 8px solid;
 border-color: #0BD676;/*#0DFF8C;*/
 padding-left:10px;
}

h2
{
 font-size: 30px;
 color:Black;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4
{
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 color:#4CAF50;
 text-decoration:underline;
}

h2, h3
{
 font-size: 1.6em;
 letter-spacing: -1px;
 margin: 0 0 0.75em 0;
}

h3
{
 font-size:1.3em;
}

h1
{
 font:bold;
}



h4
{
 font-size:1em;
 margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em;
 padding-left:1em;
}

.green
{
 border-left: 8px solid;
 border-color: #0BD676;/*#0DFF8C;*/
 padding-left:10px;
 color: #4CAF50;
 margin-left:40px;
 font-style:oblique;
}

article.centeralign
{
 text-align:center;
}

div.wrapper{
 width: 800px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

div.toolsWrapper{
 width: 980px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

div.left{
    width: 200px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:40px;
    padding-left:40px;
}

div.right{
    float:left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}


div.cc
 {
  width:200px;
  text-align:right;
  font-size:10px;
 }
 
div.ccf
 {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:12px;
 }

iframe
{
 text-align:center;
 float:center;
}

/* ===========================
   ====== Contact Form ======= 
   =========================== */

input, textarea {
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
 width: 200px;
 color: #999999;
 box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
 -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;  
}

textarea {
 width: 400px;
 height: 150px;
 max-width: 400px;
 line-height: 18px;
}

input:hover, textarea:hover,
input:focus, textarea:focus {
 border-color: 1px solid #C9C9C9;
 box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 8px;
 -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 8px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 8px; 
}

.form label {
 margin-left: 10px;
 color: #999999;
}

/* ===========================
   ====== Submit Button ====== 
   =========================== */

.submit input {
 width: 100px; 
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #474E69; 
 color: #FFF;
 border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;  
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-color:white;
}

th, td {
    padding: 15px;
}

.blue{
  background: url(blue.png) no-repeat left center;
    color: #109CEF;
    padding: 0px 40px 0px 20px;
  font-style:oblique;
 }



.red{
  background: url(red.png) no-repeat left center;
  color:#FF0000;
  padding: 0px 40px 0px 20px;
  font-style:oblique;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Audio Projects</h1>
    <blockquote>
     <h3>
          <a href="Damp">
              Class D Amplifier
          </a>
      </h3>
      <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="left">
              <img src="Damp/Damp_front.JPG"/>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
              Some text that should be next to image                          
          </div>
      </div>
  </blockquote>
</article>
```

Comment: The code snippet doesn't give the same result as 'what you get'. Can you perhaps provide code that _does what you say it does?_

Comment: yes sorry, i added the style manualy in the div so to test if that worked and it did. but why then is the css not working for the div?

Comment: Add `float :left` to the `.right ` class

Comment: How's my answer? I've edited it, and it works now.

Comment: well it seams that even my code worked properly, just not on my w10 pc, tried it under ubuntu on chrome and firefox and no problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change a few styles, and replace the `<article>` with a `<div>` (For IE support)

```css
div.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.toolsWrapper {
  width: 980px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.left {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
div.right {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}
.title {
  color: #4B9F49;
}
.inner_title {
  color: white;
}
.blockquote {
  border-left: 3px solid #0CD673;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
#article {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="article">
  <h3>
    <a href="Damp" class="title">Audio Projects</a>
  </h3>
  <blockquote class="blockquote">
    <h3>
      <a href="Damp" class="inner_title">Class D Amplifier</a>
    </h3>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="Damp/Damp_front.JPG" style="height:80px; width:200px;"/>
      <div class="right">
        Some text that is now next to the image. 
      </div>
    </div>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: @Meerweten How's my answer?

Comment: @Meerweten No it isn't

Comment: my browser say's something else: http://imgur.com/jRVPhfb
(chrome) seems to work in IE but the rest of the page is goofed up

Comment: @Meerweten Are you on a mobile browser?

Comment: not that i'm aware of, using Windows 10 and chrome Versie 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Comment: jhe thats the strange thing, its working in both mine and your snippet... just tested with firefox and IE it works in firefox too but IE just goofs the entire site

Answer (score 1):

I changed those:

```
.h1 { 
text-align: left; 
}

.h3 { 
text-align: left; 
}

div.left{ 
float: left; 
}

div.right {
width: 500px;
float: left;
margin-left: 20px;}
```

results

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rswY.png

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem is with `width` of left class division. Try to make it `auto`.

```
div.left{
   width: auto;
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1, my preferred way of doing this:

Remove the float in `.left`  take the inline left margin out of the `.right` and give both `.left` and `.right`

```
display: inline-block;
```

Giving you

```
div.left{
    width: 200px;
    /*float:left;*/
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:40px;
    padding-left:40px;
}

div.right{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 520px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

For those two classes

### Option 2:

Give both a `float:left`

```
div.left{
    width: 200px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:40px;
    padding-left:40px;
}

div.right{
    float:left;
    width: 520px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

This should cause them to stack in the same way that `inline-block` does, but floats can cause trouble later. In either case you have to limit the width on `.right` or the text will prefer to be full width and not be inline, but rather be below the image. The total width of the two divs has to be less than the available width in `.wrapper`

Comment: so like this?: 'div.left{
 width: auto;
 /*float:left;*/
 display: incline-block;
 /*margin-right:40px;
 padding-left:40px;*/
}

div.right{
 width: auto;
 display: incline-block;
 /*margin-left: 220px;*/
}'

doesn't seem to do the job

Comment: @Meerweten, updated, you've possibly misspelled 'inline-block' your comment has in**c**line

Comment: jhe spotet it after adding comment didn't fix it tought, seems like css code is no't working on that div for some reason, toucht rest of page is working on css...

Comment: @Meerweten, added another option

Comment: thanks, but still not working, i'll add my full css code, maybe somehting wrong in other part of css hat is causing this that i'm overlooking.

Comment: @Meerweten, it'll be the widths, see my last line.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is probably larger than the `.left` container (given that this is the only element that is not included in your snippet to test properly).

Try the following ...

```
img{
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

... you should probably add a class for that image, rather than styling all images this way.

Answer (score 0):

well, what i can advice you is to put the text in the same division as the image like  in paragraph tag and then give the image css attribute called "float:left" according to what you want.

thank you
hope this is going to help you

Answer (score -3):

use .classname only
instead of div.classname

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean and to explain *how* this addresses the observed behaviour. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.